# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Items' with unique index 'ndxID'

Tags: publishing, sql-database

I am getting the error below when doing a **"Republish All"**.

I did a search in the content editor for `7fe5a598-e1c9-42c3-b250-e5b2daa42043` and only found one item.

The item is marked as "locked".

If I switch the content editor to the "web" database. There are no items found for `7fe5a598-e1c9-42c3-b250-e5b2daa42043`.

If I do a search directly on the [Items] table in the "web" database.

```sql
Select * From [Items] Where [ID] like '7fe5a598-e1c9-42c3-b250-e5b2daa42043'
```

Then one row is found and the item name is the same as the item that I found in the content editor for the master database.

```
Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Items' with unique index 'ndxID'. The duplicate key value is (7fe5a598-e1c9-42c3-b250-e5b2daa42043).
The statement has been terminated. ---> System.Data.DataException: Error executing SQL command: INSERT INTO [Items] (
                        [ID], [Name], [TemplateID], [MasterID], [ParentID], [Created], [Updated]
                       )
                       VALUES(
                        @itemID, @itemName, @templateID, @branchId, @parentID, @now, @now
                       ) ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Items' with unique index 'ndxID'. The duplicate key value is (7fe5a598-e1c9-42c3-b250-e5b2daa42043).
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Execute>b__14()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.CreateItem(ID itemID, String itemName, ID templateID, ItemDefinition parent, CallContext context)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.CreateItem(ID itemID, String itemName, ID templateID, ItemDefinition parent, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.CreateItemCommand.Execute(ID itemId, String itemName, ID templateId, Item destination)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataCommands.CreateItemCommand.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.CreateItem(String itemName, Item destination, ID templateId, ID newId)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.CreateItem(String itemName, Item destination, ID templateId, ID newId, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.CreateItem(String itemName, Item destination, ID templateId, ID newId, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.PublishVersion(Item sourceVersion)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PerformAction.ExecuteAction(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PerformAction.Process(PublishItemContext context)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PublishItemPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.Process(PublishContext context)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishPipeline.Run(PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher.PublishWithResult()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

Comment: Clear item caches on your CM instance via `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`. Then try to publish.

Comment: It just worked on the second try. Will have to try the clear item cache next time.

Comment: You should write up what worked and accept it as the answer :) Then this will drop off the unanswered list.

Comment: @OwenNiblock I did like you asked and got down voted.

Comment: @OwenNiblock I am going to delete the answer.

Comment: Sorry! I only just saw this and didn't see the answer. Do any of the admins know how a resolved issue should be handled if it's not been answered?

Comment: I think it got downvoted because it was a solution to fix something instead of investigating the issue and fixing it

Comment: As a simple workaround, Can you Unpublish that particular item into web database. so that item entry(Junk entry) will get deleted from the web database, then try to republish all.